# Suggestions of German grammar books

Tags: book

Currently I am studying german through the book serie Menschen. I found out that it is a general book, it does not encompass nice grammar explanations neither many exercises for practice, it is more focused on class learning and not for self study.

I am interest in very grammar book written in english or german, preferably in english, that contains deep explainations, provides examples and also written exercises.

For example, an english teacher recommended me this book [1], which really is full of exercises and explanations. I already saw on the internet this one [2] it seens very good, but it does not contain exercises.

Based on your experience, which books would you recommend for self study and practice ? How do you apply them ?

[1] Swan, M. & Walter, C. "The good grammar book (with answers)".Oxford

[2] Durrell , M. "Hammer's German Grammar and Usage"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are the ones I have used for exercises:

- Basic German : a grammar and workbook / Heiner Schenke and Karen Seago.
- Quick fix German grammar / Susan Ashworth-Fiedler
- Collins easy learning German grammar & practice (not sure if this book is still around)
- Speed up your German : strategies to avoid common errors / Annemarie Künzl-Snodgrass, Silke Mentchen.

The "Durrell , M. "Hammer's German Grammar and Usage" is THE reference grammar and you should still use it when you need a quick look at the grammar rules.

Answer (score 4):

For deep explanations the best I've ever seen was Duden, Band 4 "die Grammatik" (Auflage 8). There is also an ebook with convenient search capabilities. 
In the not so many cases when I need something even more elaborate or specific, I just look for linguistic papers on the particular topic.